# JQuery Mortgage Calculator - The Impossible Script

Tags: php, jquery, forms, calculator

I have been dumped with this project from the last developer at my job and I have no clue what is going on, I have spent the last 8 days trying everything I can to get the calculation to output.

What should happen is the customer fills in the form, then when they press SUBMIT, the form passes the information behind the scenes, to a php file where it collates the information in the form and emails it to our company.

The customer does not get redirected, the form simply calculates their amounts and displays the calculated result above the form. whilst we get their contact information.

here is what I have been left with:

The Html Form:

```
<div class="form">

              <div id="message"></div>


              <form method="post" action="hmcib.php" name="hmcib-form" id="hmcib-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <h3>Applicant 1</h3>

                <div class="field-wrap half left">
                  <label for=a1_gro_sal><span><br /></span>Gross Annual Salary</label>
                  <input name="a1_gro_sal" type="text" id="a1_gro_sal" tabindex="1" data-format="$0,0.00" />
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap half right">
                  <label for=a1_gro_add>Gross Annual Additional Income<br /><small>(Overtime/Allowances)</small></label>
                  <input name="a1_gro_add" type="text" id="a1_gro_add" tabindex="2" data-format="$0,0.00" />
                </div>

                <h3>Applicant 2</h3>

                <div class="field-wrap half left">
                  <label for=a2_gro_sal><span><br /></span>Gross Annual Salary</label>
                  <input name="a2_gro_sal" type="text" id="a2_gro_sal" tabindex="3" data-format="$0,0.00" />
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap half right">
                  <label for=a2_gro_add>Gross Annual Additional Income<br /><small>(Overtime/Allowances)</small></label>
                  <input name="a2_gro_add" type="text" id="a2_gro_add" tabindex="4" data-format="$0,0.00" />
                </div>

                <h3>Your Details</h3>

                <div class="field-wrap half left">
                  <label for=f_name>First Name</label>
                  <input name="f_name" type="text" id="f_name" tabindex="5" />
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap half right">
                  <label for=l_name>Last Name</label>
                  <input name="l_name" type="text" id="l_name" tabindex="6" />
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap half left">
                  <label for=email>Email Address</label>
                  <input name="email" type="text" id="email" tabindex="7" />
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap half right">
                  <label for=phone>Phone Number</label>
                  <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" tabindex="8" />
                </div>

                <!--<div class="field-wrap full">
                <label for=verify>Please Enter the Code Below</label>
                <input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" tabindex="9"  class="verify" />
                <img src="/forms/image.php" class="verify-img" />
              </div>-->

              <div class="field-wrap full">
                <div class="checkbox-wrap">
                  <input name="call" type="checkbox" id="call" checked="checked" tabindex="9" />
                  <label for=call>Would you like an adviser call you to give you further information?</label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="field-wrap full">
                <div class="checkbox-wrap">
                  <input name="agree" type="checkbox" id="agree" tabindex="10" />
                  <label for=agree>Declaration: I understand that by submitting my details you will hold my personal data on your database.</label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="field-wrap full">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Calculate" />
              </div>
```

Here is the jquery script:

```
 $('#hmcib-form').submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled').after('<img src="loading.gif" class="loader" />');

        $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
        $('#message').hide();

        var checkbox_value_call = '';
            if (jQuery('input#call').is(':checked'))
                checkbox_value_call = 1;
            else
                checkbox_value_call = 0;

        var checkbox_value_agree = '';
            if (jQuery('input#agree').is(':checked'))
                checkbox_value_agree = 1;
            else
                checkbox_value_agree = 0;

        $.post(action, {
            a1_gro_sal: $('#a1_gro_sal').val(),
            a1_gro_add: $('#a1_gro_add').val(),
                a2_gro_sal: $('#a2_gro_sal').val(),
                a2_gro_add: $('#a2_gro_add').val(),
            f_name: $('#f_name').val(),
            l_name: $('#l_name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            call: checkbox_value_call,
            agree: checkbox_value_agree,
//          verify: $('#verify').val()
        },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#hmcib-form img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: ($('body').offset().top)}, 750);
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#hmcib-form').slideUp('slow');
            }
        );

        });

        return false;

    });
```

This is the PHP File which gathers the information and emails it to our company:

```
    <?php

if( $_POST ){

    $to = "us@ourcompany.com";

    $subject = "query from calculator form";    

    $fields = $_POST['a1_gro_sal'] . ' ' . $_POST['a1_gro_add'] . ' ' . $_POST['a2_gro_sal'] . ' ' . $_POST['a2_gro_add']  . ' ' . $_POST['f_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['l_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['email'] . ' ' . $_POST['phone'];   


    $gross1 = $_POST['a1_gro_sal'];
    $gross2 = $_POST['a1_gro_add'];
    $gross3 = $_POST['a2_gro_sal'];
    $gross4 = $_POST['a2_gro_add'];
    $fname = $_POST['f_name'];
    $lname = $_POST['l_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $fields);

    ?>

    <table class="table table-striped" border="0">

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
     <div class="alert alert-info">
      <strong>Success</strong>, Form Submitted Successfully...
     </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><?php echo $fname ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><?php echo $lname ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Your eMail</td>
    <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Contact No</td>
    <td><?php echo $phone; ?></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <?php}
```

When I submit the form I just get the table displayed above the form with the users information, basically what is in the php file I echo out above the form, but I simply do not know how or where I would calculate the result to show the customer how much they could borrow.

I have also been left with this file also which I think must do the calculations but it is huge!! so I dont want to add it here, I will just add a link to it instead.

[Calc Script File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48562823/calx.js)

[Calc Config File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48562823/calx-config.js)

I have literally hit a brick wall and I cannot work out what to do to get the calculated value of the user inputted values to output on the screen upon submission of the form. I would greatly and desperately appreciate any help at all please.

Thank you so much. Feel free to ask for any further information and I will be more than happy to help.

I am thinking its something I am missing in the php file, i am just not sure at all.

Comment: https://www.upwork.com/

Comment: your question is too broad, and it doesnt actually look like you tried to solve anything first. Identify the issue first then comeback. I'll give you a tip: It's not the PHP file, the calculation is being done with JS

Comment: I am so sorry if this question has caused offence or been provided wrong, I dont want anyone to do the work for me, I have spent 8 days working most of this out, I just hit a brick wall and couldn't get any further, so I thought this would be the best place to share it. Thanks anyway. Is it possible you could tell me even if the external cacl JS files are being used?

Comment: I also asked here at SO because I wanted to learn how the script worked, if I paid someone to do it I would be in the same position I am now and still no nothing of what was going on, I thought because this is where the experts are, it would help me have a greater understanding of working this out myself with a little guidance, that's all I meant.